# How do you import AD Security groups into SharePoint?

Tags: permissions, active-directory

How do you import Active Directory security groups for SP into SharePoint itself?

I have created the group and added the users, just want to have that group displayed when you go to the Site Permissions for a particular site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the AD group to one of the built in SharePoint groups like SiteName Owners or SiteName Visitors.

Comment: hey Robert...this is Nick (Xcluziv) from TE...lol. We actually have quite a few groups in AD for SharePoint for different sites and within the group with have 3 subgroups which are (Owner, Member, and Viewer). Is there a way to get those particular groups inside SP since its quite a few

Comment: You don't have to add them one by one. The box where you specific which user or group can be multiple users or multiple groups seperated by semicolons.

Comment: I was able to add the groups successfully

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Robert's suggestion, you can also grant an AD group permissions (Full Control, Read etc) directly  instead of adding them to an existing SharePoint group).

Might be worth noting that with SharePoint you have to "grant access" to a group as opposed to "import" a group, in order for them to show up on the site permissions page.

Comment: Gotcha Paul. Where do you import these groups within SharePoint?